# Exit rails console after long output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would've thought this would be an easy thing, but when I use the rails console, if I query a variable that has multi-page output, I can continue scrolling until the console yields `(END)`  but then I can't get out of that state without <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd>, which requires me to restart said rails console to continue.  I'd like to just exit that output, but <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and every other combo I can think of simply do nothing.  I'm certain there *is* a way to do it, can someone put me straight?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "Q"? For "Quit"? It sounds like you're in a pager...

Comment: that was it, thanks.  Not sure why I didn't think of it.  I'll mark as answered if you answer rather than comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're in a [pager](http://www.slackbook.org/html/file-commands-pagers.html). Press "Q", for "Quit".